# What Scala Map methods to override

Tags: scala, counter, scala-collections, scala-2.10, scala-2.11

I want to create a `Counter[A]` data structure (inspired by Python's [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)) that extends `Map[A, Int]` that simply keeps counts of occurrences of items of type `A`. I want it to have 2 extra methods `add(item: A)` and `remove(item: A)` which increments/decrements counter associated with `item` and ofcourse I also want all the nice Scala collection methods like `map`, `filter` etc so I probably should be extending `Map[A, Int]`. But, I am confused regarding what are the minimal set of methods should I override/implement from `Map` for the other Scala collection methods to simply work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider replacing inheritance with delegation. In other words, your class can extend `Map[A, Int]`, but it should contain a private `Map[A, Int]` member. All calls to your class simply delegate the same calls to the member.

Here is a partial implementation of my suggestion:

```
class MyClass[A, Int] extends collection.immutable.Map[A, Int] {
  private val map = collection.immutable.Map.empty[A, Int]

  def get(key: A): Option[Int] = {
    map.get(key)
  }

  def iterator: Iterator[(A, Int)] = {
    map.iterator
  }

  def -(key: A): Map[A, Int] = {
    map - key
  }

  def +[B1 >: Int](kv: (A, B1)): Map[A, B1] = {
    map + kv
  }
}
```

Comment: But then I would have to delegate all the 100 or so methods in Map right? I want to override the smallest set of methods...

Comment: No. The class I provided above represents the minimum you have to implement. So another class could now say `val map = new MyMap[Int, Int]`. Because `filter`, for example, is a concrete method in the `Map` trait, you don't have to implement it. But calling it might confuse clients with its behavior. So you could use your IDE to implement everything with `super`, or you could have your class not extend `Map`. Hopefully, others will chime in with other better solutions as I too am still learning Scala.

Comment: I just implemented it here: https://github.com/pathikrit/scalgos/commit/597baeb406d92c179e919faff3c3fe1d8141193e

Answer (score 1):

You should looks at this:
http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html
It explains with details process of building new collections in scala.
If you don't want to read whole article you can jump directly to section 'Integrating new sets and maps' which by example shows how to build new kind of map - exactly what you want to do.